# How do I scrape all the information of this website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a trouble with requests that I can't get requests from the website: https://www.realestate.com.au/neighbourhoods/adelaide-5000-sa

```
import requests
url = "https://www.realestate.com.au/neighbourhoods/adelaide-5000-sa"

r = requests(url)

print(r.text)
```

The result:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>realestate.com.au - 403 Error - Permission Denied</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <hr color="#e4002b">
        <br/>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;<img src="//s1.rui.au.reastatic.net/rui-static/img/rea-logo-v3.png" alt="realestate.com.au Australia lives here" width=200px>
        <font face="Helvetica">
            <h1>&nbsp; 403 - Permission Denied</h1>
            <p>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; You do not have permission to retrieve the URL or link you requested,
            <br/><br/>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; If you think this was a mistake please call <b>1300 134 174</b> or e-mail <b>customercare@realestate.com.au</b>
            <br/>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; and quote the reference number <b>&#32;&#35;18&#46;8feaab71&#46;1644380191&#46;7ed3a87</b>
        </font>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also add headers for this: requests.get(url)

```
headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.124 Safari/537.36",
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

But the result is also not as expected.

The result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><script src="/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/ips.js?KP2_UIDz=0DETW9mNWboJXNVKMmWs4ugsDT3iOBMjnnifyH1JVr4sCw2xb90A1wDQxxHIc8J3YRp8zuAsESWfDZZR9ytyVuGUqYpXWZOln6ZcXMAzvdFUWVAjOaofLTbO8Gvj7T5pvjab68eFE1oJDwaBndMBQuK2w"></script></body></html>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This requires the cookie in your header along with the user-agent.

Using the browser developer tools, get the cookie and put it into your request. It will work fine. However, make sure your user-agent matches too. The site checks the user-agent against the one given the cookie.

```
import requests

headers = {
        'Cookie': '*** your cookie here ***',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.124 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

print(response.text)
print(response.status_code)
```

Gave me this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie ie8"></html><![endif]--><!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie ie9"></html><![endif]--><html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  try {
    if (Object.defineProperty !== undefined) {
      Object.defineProperty(document, 'referrer', {
        value: "",
        writable: false
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {}
</script>

<script>window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam-cell.nr-data.net","errorBeacon":"bam-cell.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"1d1110a9fb","applicationID":"33095795","transactionName":"dlxWFkpaXQgHQhZqUVtSTBBZGmIRAEVLW2hHXF4LVFBwFBIffnxsFRxWB1FSWQYNRUtRV1pXS00CVFUAEFVKSg==","queueTime":1,"applicationTime":345,"agent":""}</script>
...
```